# Solving the equation $\{a^{-1}\}=\{a^2\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $\{x\}$ be the fractional part of a real number $x$. If $a$ is a positive real number with $\{a^{-1}\}=\{a^2\}$ and $2<a^2<3$, find $a^{12}-144a^{-1}$.

This is probably an AIME problem. But I don't know from which year it is. Here is my solution of the problem:

Because $2<a^2<3\implies\frac1{\sqrt3}<a^{-1}<\frac1{\sqrt2}$, we have $\lfloor a^{-1}\rfloor=0$ and $\lfloor a^2\rfloor=2$. So the equation is
$\begin{align}a^{-1}=a^2-2 &\implies a^3-2a-1=0\\ &\implies (a+1)(a^2-a-1)=0\\ &\implies a=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2.\end{align}$
Now with some boring calculations, we can find $a^{12}-144a^{-1}$. But this is very much dependant on computations. Is there some other way to find $a^{12}-144a^{-1}$ that is not much dependant on computational skills? Also as we obtained $a=\phi$, can we use Fibonacci numbers here?

Comment: It may help that $a^2=a+1$ and $1/a=a-1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Martin R says, use can use $\phi^{-1}=\phi-1$. You can also use the fact that $\phi^n=F_n\phi+F_{n-1}$ where $F_n$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. (This follows by induction: $\phi^1=1\phi+0=F_1\phi+F_0$ and $\phi^{n+1}=\phi(F_n\phi+F_{n-1})=F_n\phi^2+F_{n-1}\phi=(F_n+F_{n-1})\phi+F_n=F_{n+1}\phi+F_n$, again using an identity suggested by Martin R.) This reduces $\phi^{12}-144\phi^{-1}$ to $F_{12}\phi+F_{11}-144(\phi-1)$ and $F_{11}=89$ and $F_{12}=144$ are much less cumbersome to compute.

Answer (score 5):

Since $a^2=a+1$ we have
$$a^3=a^2+a=2a+1$$
$$a^4=2a^2+a=3a+2$$
$$a^5=3a^2+2a=5a+3$$
and clearly the powers of $a$ reduce to multiples of $a$ plus offsets, with Fibonacci number coefficients. Hence
$$a^{12}=144a+89$$
$$a^{-1}=a-1$$
$$a^{12}-144a^{-1}=89+144=233$$